# Highcharts, Show specific tick on a datetime xaxis type

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I have a `xAxis` which is in datetime format on highcharts.

I send millisecond position of `xAxis` to place point on chart.

The total time on `xAxis` is about 2 years.

But I want to show tick only where there are some points (about 6 points).

For the moment, ticks are show at regular interval with the date.

Here is what I have :

[image]

And what I need :

[image]

thanks,

Comment: Could you please post an example of the working code? I cant seem to achieve the desired results jsfiddle.net/blowsie/7hdpz

Comment: @Dragouf were you able to find a solution for this? None of the solutions below are seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is possible,**

you can use

```
xAxis.labels.formatter
```

this is for formatting labels, you have to maintain a {realaxis:{label:labelValue},realaxis:{label:labelValue} ...} Object for formatting labels

set the

> xAxis.tickInterval

for number of calls for label formatting function you have provided

Comment: Could you please post an example of this code? I cant seem to achieve the desired results http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/7hdpz/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the ticks as needed, what you could do is implement a [custom formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--formatter). Basically, you would only plot a point if the value was the same as in your data:

```
var data = []; //assuming this is your array of timestamps

var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
    //other options
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                //some cleanup may be required, but this is the general form of the solution
                if (this.value in data) {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, it's seems it don't work because formatter is call just to format an already placed tick. not on each unit of the x axis. I tried to reduce pointInterval but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not do that. Highcharts only draws the ticks at some regular interval. If they don't appear in regular interval then they are not ticks any more. 
You can try setting minorTickInterval, but still it all depends on your data, where they appear on the timeline.